# Can we use a Boolean as env variable in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I'm trying to make an app on Firebase functions (a Puppeteer app) and I do have the following in a `.json` file.
It is working great locally.

```
"custom": {
  "following_training": false,
  "worked": false
}
```

But when I do push it remotely and try to setup my code with `firebase functions:config:set app="$(cat .env-production.json)"` (to avoid typing a long `.json` config env variable string essentially), I do have the following warning:
`HTTP Error: 400, Invalid value at 'variable.text' (TYPE_STRING), false`

So yeah, it's basically telling me to only send **that** kind of json:

```
"custom": {
  "following_training": "false",
  "worked": "false"
}
```

Then, it is working remotely if I do add that [to-bool package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-bool) to actually check inside of the code if `toBool(local_vars.app.custom.worked) == false`...

Isn't there a cleaner way to do it...?
In the firebase [config-env documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), there is actually no example about a boolean field.

I do get the expected stuff when typing `firebase functions:config:get` but something strange too is that I do not have any variables in the Google Cloud Platform function's dashboard (I get refreshed code, Puppeteer's option settings, and so on..).

Not sure if it's anyhow related.

The env vars may just be used by Firebase and do not need to be sent to the GCP.

EDIT: working great, not a **Firebase** issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment variables are only string types.

There's no typing (other than string) of shell|environment variables.

You should set a boolean in your code based on the value (or non-value) of the (environment value) string.